# Access Denied when logging in using Safari

Tags: users, ssl, uri, cookies

When I login to example.com via Safari web browser, I get a message that says "Access Denied. You are not authorized to access this page."

I can login properly when using Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

I can login properly using Safari in the local instance of the site.

`$base_url` is set as `http://www.example.com` and `$cookie_domain` is set as `.example.com`. I've also tried commenting out $cookie_comain.

I've already added

```
// Change base_url to HTTPS ($base_url may be explicitly set by settings.php)
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
  global $base_url;
  $base_url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $base_url);
}
```

to the Secure Page module as suggested in https://drupal.org/node/863562#comment-3266304.

I've cleared the Drupal cache and Safari browser cache.

$conf['https'] is set to TRUE.

This happens on Safari 5.1.7, but not on Safari 3.2.2.

Compared the Http Headers with another Drupal site using Secure Pages. Didn't find anything fishy.

Comment: It's almost certainly cache - clear your cookies too

Comment: Done that. Issue persists.

Comment: did you ever solved this? I think I have the same issue